# Чи є синонім "окатій яєчні"?

Tags: синоніми, from-russian

У відео на Youtube почула вислів: "*оката яєчня*". Мали на увазі яєчню, у якій жовток не змішаний з білком. В тлумачному словнику таки є цей [термін](http://sum.in.ua/s/okatyj). Але ніколи досі не чула, щоб його вживали в розмові. Чи є більш поширений український відповідник російській "*яичнице глазунье*"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У [- Російсько-українському академічному словнику 1924–33рр. (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BD*&scope=all&highlight=on) знаходжу Ваш відповідник, а також й інший:

> 2) **яє́шня випускна́, яє́шня ока́та**.

[Російсько-український словник 1930р. (О. Ізюмов)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BD*&scope=all&highlight=on) містить таку інформацію:

> **Глазун** – ока́нь, -ня́; **-нья – ока́та, -тої**.

Ще один цікавий варіант містить і [Словарь росийсько-український 1893–1898рр. (М.Уманець, А.Спілка.)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BD*&scope=all&highlight=on):

> Глазу́нья = 1. ока́та, банька́та; бачу́ча бистроо́ка. — **Яйчница глазу́нья = **Яє́шня не розбо́втана**, випускна́.**

Трішки виправлюсь. :-)

Думала, що правильний варіант лише "яєЧня", а не "яєШня" і що при перекладі виникла помилка, проте натрапила на статтю [Оката яєчня, лАте, еспресо: найпоширеніші помилки у назвах їжі та напоїв](http://kava.lviv.ua/ua/article/5863/~okata-yajechnya-late-espreso-najposhyrenishi-pomylky-u-nazvakh-izhi-ta-napoiv), в якій дає інтерв’ю Олександр Авраменко. То ж науковець каже:

> НЕПРАВИЛЬНО: глазунья (яєчня з нерозлитим жовтком).
>
> ***ПРАВИЛЬНО***: **оката яєчня**.
>
> До речі, *правильними* є обидва варіанти – *яєчня та яєшня*. Проте у словниках *«яєшня»* позначають як *застаріле слово*.

Отже, є такі варіанти (синоніми): ***яєчня випускна́, оката, не розбовтана.***

Я, наприклад, часто у розмові чую термін "яєчня оката".